# Unwanted warning message with g++

Tags: c++, ruby, g++, warnings, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to write a c++ extension for Ruby. In addition to the main file, I have a file `extconf.rb`:

```
require "mkmf"
$libs += " -lstdc++ "
create_makefile("file_name")
```

and, after doing `ruby extconf.rb`, when I try to compile it with `g++` by typing `make`, I get the warning:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
```

I read that it is not harmful, but is there a way to avoid this warning? There is a person with the same problem [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/819144-c-warning), but the solution cannot be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the resulting `Makefile` created after running `create_makefile` and remove the `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` from there.

Comment: Is there a way to minimally modify some related code and do that automatically? After reading your answer, I am looking at `mkmf.rb`, but can't find anything that says `Wdeclaration-after-statement`.

Comment: I tried changing ` config["CPPFLAGS"]`, but it still gives warning. But, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this in your `extconf.rb`:

```
$warnflags.gsub!('-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '') if $warnflags
```

the `if $warnflags` is needed because `mkmf` changed in Ruby 1.9.3; without it you'll get `` undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass `` if you try to build on Ruby 1.9.2. You shouldn’t get the c++ warning in 1.9.2 though: the default warnings Ruby uses changed in 1.9.3 and these have been added.

**Update:**

This is probably better:

```
CONFIG['warnflags'].gsub!('-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '')
```

`$warnflags` gets populated from this, but this doesn't need the `if $warnflags` for < 1.9.3.

Comment: I did that, and the warning message reduced from giving two of them to one, but I still get one.

Comment: @sawa the same warning (`declaration-after-statement`), or a different one?

Comment: Even with `CONFIG['warnflags']`..., I still get one warning.

Comment: @sawa Where in the generated makefile do you delete `-Wdeclaration-after-statement`? Does it appear twice in there?

Comment: I didn't delete it int the Makefile. I put the line that you suggest in extconf.rb.

Comment: @sawa I mean in the other solution above, where in the Makefile does the line appear. On my machine '-Wdeclaration-after-statement' appears once in `warnflags` in the Makefile without my fix. I'm wondering if your system has that flag set somewhere else that `mkmf` is picking up.

Comment: I was wrong. They were two different warning messages. I did `sub!` to remove both of them, and they disappeared. Thanks for the help.